# AngularJS <input> validation with <tr ng-repeat>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs and I DO NOT have a `<form>` (IMPORTANT!!!)

My template html is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="usage in usages">
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="usage.calls" required/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="" ng-disabled="disabled()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-saved" ng-click="save(usage)"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want change CSS on `<input>` if empty and put disabled save action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` and test for `undefined`. 
Also, you need to use a button for the `disabled` attribute to work.

Check below:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.usages = [{
      calls: 1
    },{
      calls: 2
    },{
      calls: 3
    }];
    
    $scope.isDefined = function(value) {
       return typeof value !== 'undefined';
    }
    
    $scope.save = function(usage) {
      console.log(usage)
    }
        
  })
```

```css
.err{ border: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="usage in usages">
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-class="{'err': !isDefined(usage.calls)}" ng-model="usage.calls" required/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-disabled="!isDefined(usage.calls)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-saved" ng-click="save(usage)">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```